# Convert Array of Objects into multiple JSON objects in Nodejs

Tags: node.js

I need to split the array of objects into multiple objects.

I have a sample array of objects like below shown.

```
var data= [
  { Date: '1394351059', Amount: '621', Price: '0.01' },
  { Date: '1394351073', Amount: '620', Price: '0.01' },
  { Date: '1394427477', Amount: '620', Price: '0.01' },
  { Date: '1394427596', Amount: '620.5', Price: '0.01'}
]
```

Expected output result like this:

```
{ Date: '1394351059', Amount: '621', Price: '0.01' }
{ Date: '1394351073', Amount: '620', Price: '0.01' }
```

I Need to show this result in Node.js.But I am unable to get the individual json Objects in NodeJS. please give me result as of below showed way in Nodejs.

Comment: Please edit your question removing duplicated sections, it's not really clear what you want to obtain.

Comment: Please check now i have edited the data

Comment: What did you try? Are you saying you can't filter `data`?

Comment: We can filter data.But what i am saying is that.
I have data in array of Objects.
This array of Objects is converted into Multiple json objects.

Comment: So... I'm not really sure I got what you mean, are you looking for something like https://lodash.com/docs#find?

Comment: Not Exactly. I need output like Individual Json objects.Please check my Expected output.If not understand please let me know i will try to explain more.

Comment: Will you please any one can answer.

Comment: You cannot have a series of objects as return from a function without them being in a data structure of some sort, that is why I am confused :)

Comment: Try `data.splice(0,2)`

Answer (score 0):

To filter/parse the array, you just need a simple for loop. While it remains unclear what you want to do with the individual objects, something like the following should get you started.

```
for(var i=0; i < array.length; i++){        
console.log(array[i]);    };
```

Replace array with the name of your array.

If you clarify what you want to do with the returned results, that would make your question better.